# EGit fetch failing: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Tags: https, egit, gitblit

I upgraded from Gitblit 1.3.2 to 1.5.0, which uses SSL by default.  Attempting to fetch from the remote using Eclipse + EGit brings up the error dialog:

```
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

I'm able to clone from the terminal after setting the following:

```
git config http.sslVerify false
git config --unset http.proxy  
git config --unset https.proxy
```

I've set the Window->Preferences->General->Network to bypass the proxy to the server, but I still get the error trying to access the remote in Eclipse.

Is this a JVM version/vendor issue?

Comment: You don't have to use https with Gitblit.  Having said that... what version of Java are you using to run Eclipse?

Comment: Using the old URL (:8080), I'm getting `302`.  Java version: java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: 302 is for a redirect/move. Have you set server.redirectToHttpsPort=true ?

Comment: Schoolboy error:  I had overwritten the 1.5.0 gitblit.properties with the 1.3.2 file. Works now that I made the corrections you suggested to the correct version of the properties file. (thanks)